# Loop over one column and fill rows in fucntion Pandas Dataframe Python

Tags: python, pandas, loops, dataframe

I am trying to loop over a dataframe. Especially through the date column so means for every date I get the x, y and z values for that date and fill it into my defined function. Somehow I am not sure how i can properly call it.  My code looks like the following:

```
import pandas as pd

def calc_funct(x, y, z):

    func = x*y*z

    return func

if __name__ == '__main__':

    df = pd.read_csv('C:/Data.csv')

    for column in df:

        results = calc_funct(df['x'], df['y'], df['z'])
        print(result)
```

The input looks like the following:

```
           date   x   y   z
    0  2017-11-11  18  17   7
    1  2017-11-11  16  19   3
    2  2017-11-11  13  14   2
    3  2017-11-11  12  13   1
    4  2017-11-11  11  12   9
    5  2017-11-11  10  11  10
    6  2017-11-11  21  10  11
    7  2017-11-12  13  19  12
    8  2017-11-13  18  17  12
    9  2017-11-14   9  10  20
   10  2017-11-15   2  20  13
   11  2017-11-18  13  13   9
   12  2017-11-19  18  14  16
   13  2017-11-20  14  11  19
   14  2017-11-21  18  15  19
```

For date 2017-11-11 I would calculate the values (e.g. add/subtract all values them at that date) and store it e.g. in a list. Then iterate over the next date 2017-11-12 etc...

Comment: What is your expected output? Do you want a new column which gives the result of multiplying x, y and z for each row of your DataFrame?

Comment: @Ben, Thanks a lot for your answer. My Output should be just an print statement for every date it should print the result calculated based on the function defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want all the columns + the new column which is the result of your function, you can do so:

```
df['result'] = calc_funct(df['x'], df['y'], df['z'])
```

or just `date` and `result` with this other line of code:

```
df = df[['date','result']]
```

**EDIT**

```
result = []
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    result.append(row['date'])
    result.append(calc_funct(row['x'], row['y'], row['z']))
print result
```

Comment: And the ouput should be more stored outside of a dataframe.

Comment: what do you mean with "outside of a dataframe"?

Comment: just as an value in an array for later processing

Comment: I modified the post. In this way you have a list

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is the right way. But how can I include the date into the output and in addition why do I receive in output many time the same output?

Comment: Do you want a list with tuples in this format (date, result)?

Comment: something like: 2017-11-11 2142
2017-11-12 2964
2017-11-13 3672
2017-11-14 1800
2017-11-15 520
2017-11-18 1521
2017-11-19 4032
2017-11-20 2926
2017-11-21 5130

Comment: I edit the post, in the for loop you shloud replace `df` by `row`. Moreover, you can consider using list comphrension : `result = [calc_funct(row['x'], row['y'], row['z']) for index, row in df.iterrows()]`

Comment: @Thomas, Perfect thanks a lot. That is what I was looking for. And thanks for the post below. I need that too but for soemthing else.

Comment: I still have one question concenring the loop. how is it when I want to fill data into my function based on the date. How can I adjust the loop? Hope it is clear?

Comment: Can you make an example? I didnt get your question totally

Comment: then you have to use: grouped = df.groupby('date'). But please open a new question if you want something specific

Comment: @Joe, I think a new question would be better. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @MCM welcome. if my answer was good for your first question, please consider to accept and upvote it :)

Answer (score 4):

In pandas you can use the `apply` method.

```
df.apply(lambda v : calc_funct(v["x"], v["y"], v["z"]), axis=1)
```

Note `axis=1` for iterate over rows, `axis=0` is for iteration over columns.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. How can I print the results as the following: Date and the result?

Comment: just add `print` : `df.apply(lambda v : print(calc_funct(v["x"], v["y"], v["z"])), axis=1)`

Comment: Note that you can add store the result in the original dataframe : `df["result"] = df.apply(lambda v : calc_funct(v["x"], v["y"], v["z"]), axis=1)`