# Loop Dataframe Pandas Python on specific dates

Tags: python, pandas, loops, date, dataframe

I am trying to loop over a dataframe and got a solution described here [Old Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48519553/loop-over-one-column-and-fill-rows-in-fucntion-pandas-dataframe-python). Somehow I am looking for something more specific, which I just realized. The loop should calculate the results and write the output of every date into a csv file, where the csv file contains as filename the date and in the file should be the date and the result. I woud prefer using the loop and just extend the code.

```
import pandas as pd

def calc_funct(x):

    func = x^2

    return func

def calc_funct2(y):

    func = y^3

    return func

if __name__ == '__main__':

    df = pd.read_csv('C:/Data.csv')

    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        result = []            
        result = (calc_funct(row['x']))
        print(result)
```

The input looks like the following:

```
           date   x   y   z
    0  2017-11-11  18  17   7
    1  2017-11-11  16  19   3
    2  2017-11-11  13  14   2
    3  2017-11-11  12  13   1
    4  2017-11-11  11  12   9
    5  2017-11-11  10  11  10
    6  2017-11-11  21  10  11
    7  2017-11-12  13  19  12
    8  2017-11-13  18  17  12
    9  2017-11-14   9  10  20
   10  2017-11-15   2  20  13
   11  2017-11-18  13  13   9
   12  2017-11-19  18  14  16
   13  2017-11-20  14  11  19
   14  2017-11-21  18  15  19
```

To mak it more easy to understand I included an hand made examle which I wanted to make it more automatic because I am getting all data in an dataframe and just get the proper data out of it which depends on a date and extended it to make it more clear. Maybe my explanation is just too bad and try to make just a way how it can be easier to understaood:

```
   for loop date 1 (2017-11-11):

   result = []

     for loop through values for the dedictaed date (Note every result is an own object at the end):

        result = OwnObject(calc_funct(x),calc_funct2(y/100))

    store results in a csv file with the date given (2017-11-11)   

   Loop date 2 (2017-11-12):
         result = OwnObject(calc_funct(x),calc_funct2(y/100))

    store results in a csv file with the date given (2017-11-12)
```

etc etc...

For the time being the OwnObject is not so important

Comment: "I woud prefer using the loop and just extend the code." Why? If you're using pandas in the first place, would you not prefer a vectorized approach (ballpark, 100x faster) and use `to_csv` after?

Comment: @roganjosh, why i prefer a loop is that I have some more functions to feed and just get extracts from my dataframe based on the dates. speed is not the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I strongly recommend going pandas way. Then why do you use pandas at all? To easily read and save csv?

Maybe this inspires you.

This is how your date looks like.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([
['2017-11-11', 18, 17, 7],
['2017-11-11', 16, 19, 3],
['2017-11-12', 10, 4, 5],
['2017-11-11', 1, 2, 3],
], columns=['date', 'x', 'y', 'z'])
```

First, you need to be sure that your values are formatted correctly.

```
df.date = pd.to_datetime(df.date)
df.x = pd.to_numeric(df.x)
df.y = pd.to_numeric(df.y)
df.z = pd.to_numeric(df.z)

print(df.date.dtype) # datetime64[ns]
```

If you don't want to apply changes in place you can easily do it in new column.

```
df = df.assign(x2=df.x.apply(calc_funct))
df = df.assign(y2=df.y.apply(calc_funct2))
df

        date   x   y  z  x2  y2
0 2017-11-11  18  17  7  16  18
1 2017-11-11  16  19  3  18  16
2 2017-11-12  10   4  5   8   7
3 2017-11-11   1   2  3   3   1
```

After that, you can do grouping, aggregation where you can apply calculations to a group of the results for a specific date.

With this approach, you can do as many calculations as you want and this is a real investment in performance and your education.

**Update**

You can add objects to data frame as well.

```
class OwnObject(object):
    def __init__(self, x2, y2=None):
        self._x2 = x2
        self._y2 = y2

    def __repr__(self):
        # Just for representation reason
        return 'OwnObject({}, {})'.format((self._x2), (self._y2))

def create_object(row):
    return OwnObject(row.x2, row.y2)

df = df.assign(my_object = df.apply(create_object, axis=1))

df
          date  x   y   z   x2  y2  my_object
0   2017-11-11  18  17  7   16  18  OwnObject(16, 18)
1   2017-11-11  16  19  3   18  16  OwnObject(18, 16)
2   2017-11-12  10  4   5   8   7   OwnObject(8, 7)
3   2017-11-11  1   2   3   3   1   OwnObject(3, 1)
```

If you want to get list of all created objects:

```
list(df.my_object)
# outputs: [OwnObject(16, 18), OwnObject(18, 16), OwnObject(8, 7), OwnObject(3, 1)]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the example. I tried to make the stuff above clearer. Is that also possible doing it with Pandas? I dont want at the end to store it in a dataframe

Comment: I did not clearly understand you, you mean aggregation?

Comment: OwnObject is just an object which will be also stored later and used for another calculation I do not mention in my example. I thin the general logic should be clear right?

Comment: Thanks a lot, Your are saving my day!!!!! Now I understand where you rae going with your comments. One more additional question. In case I have a function defined which needs two variables filled which I take from two different column in my dataframe how would that work, e.g. def calc3(x,y)

Comment: Yeah, for example `df = df.assign(xy=some_x_calc(df.x) + df.y/100)` or `df = df.assign(xy2=lambda row: sum_x_and_y(row.x, row.y))`. You can write just `df.x + df.y` if you don`t want to assign new column to df. I suggest you to use jupyter notebook and pdb debugger to play around and see what kind of operations are available in specific moment of code.

Answer (score 1):

You can [write csv](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) at the end of your for loop :

```
store_result = {}
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    result = []
    result = (calc_funct(row['x'], row['y'], row['z']))
    store_result[date] = result
    with open(row["date"] + '.csv', 'wb') as csvfile:
        csv_writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
        csv_writer.writerow(row["date"] + "," + str(result))
```

Comment: @Thomas, yes this is close to what I am looking. How would it be if I would not store it into a csv file but just use it for further calculation and then store it. I just want to make sure that I am really just looping over the dates. Sorry if it too complicated explaied

Comment: @MCM not sure to understand your request. If you want to keep a track of the result you should definitely use pandas.

Comment: @MCM do whatever you want with `result` from `result = (calc_funct(row['x'], row['y'], row['z']))` and then substitute that result into `row["date"] + "," + str(result)` instead of `result`

Comment: @roganjosh, can you show it in the result of Thomas and edit it in it?

Comment: @MCM I'm not going to edit this post for something like that. You've demonstrated plenty of python knowledge in your question to handle this; `result2 = result * 2` then `csv_writer.writerow(row["date"] + "," + str(result2))`, for example. IMO this post answers your question as it is.

Comment: @roganjosh, Sorry still dont get the answer. What I want is having the result array calculated for a date, it is of a second order to store it, but more calculate everything per date, the do other stuff and store it, and then jump to the next date etc etc. hope it is clearer?

Comment: @MCM it is less clear to me. There is no "result array" in your question, because `calc_funct(x, y, z)` returns a scalar. Since you're iterating through the DF by row, there is no array.

Comment: @roganjosh, there is an array called result. This gets overwritten. But I want that it gets calculated per date, e.g. I have several values for one date. I need to use it for other calculations, because i wanted to make the example above simple. To make it simple, I just want to iterate through the dates and perform the calculation. I tried to expand the example to make it maybe more clear.

Comment: @MCM I edit the post to add variable store_result. It is a dict with date as key and result as value. You can use it to keep a track of your record. You can also transform this dict in [pandas Series](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.html)

Comment: @Thomas, thanks a lot. I tried to make it more clear as explained above. Hope it is clearer what I want? The example above should be clearer?